# How can an Android fragment in a TabLayout read its own index?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

If I wanted to display the "page number" for each tabbed fragment, how can a fragment tell its own index within a TabLayout (as opposed to `tabLayout.getSelectedTabPosition`() which returns index of the currently selected tab)?

Comment: Didn't understand your question properly, can you explain it further what you are trying to achieve here.

Comment: Doesn't the `PlaceholderFragment` template already do this?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve that when creating fragment

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int index) {
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInteger("index", index);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    int index = getArguments().getInteger("index", 0);
}
```

And in the adapter, pass in the position

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
    // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
    return MyFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately fragment instantiation is being handled by a framework so I won't be able to take this approach myself.

Comment: I'm using MvvmCross.

Comment: I'm not familiar with that but it should have the option to handle argument or if it doesn't you can extend it and add the ability to set argument to fragments @stovroz